# Run Mocha.js in the browser via npm script

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, browser, mocha.js

I want to move some unit tests of my app to the browser instead of running in the Node.js environment.
I've seen some examples online but what is not clear to me if it's possible to create a npm script that runs the browser tests and tell me if they've failed or not so I can use in CICD, making sure every test is passing.

What is not clear to me is: is there a way to not having to manually checking the tests result?

Comment: If you're using CI/CD and don't want to manually check the result, why not run it in the backend as normal?

Comment: Oh good question. The thing is: the feature I want to test, which is a graph, is more reliable if I run on a browser

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about your use case as an [edit] to the post? If the dupe doesn't solve it for you I can reopen.